# Does Apple Passbook include call backs to get a count on how many times a pass was opened..? or activated.?

Tags: ibeacon, passbook

I am trying to create a pass that will auto open when its near a beacon.?

I can achieve that. However I would like to get a count on my server as to how many times the pass was auto opened to see how many users who downloaded the pass were close to the location..?

how can i do that.?

Comment: Short answer - no, if it were possible then it would be documented in the Passbook web service specification.

Comment: I believe @PassKit's comment is the correct answer.  It should be entered as such so it may be accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer - no, if it were possible then it would be documented in the [Passbook web service specification](https://developer.apple.com/passbook).